# How to tell if a function uses a system call

Tags: c++, operating-system, system-calls, cin

I am learning about system calls and am starting to understand them. I understand that you shouldn't call them directly (as it makes your code less portable) and that you should call API's instead. However, is there a way to tell if a certain function uses a system call? I read that not all functions require system calls (some library functions). For example, fopen will use a system call eventually. My questions are:

1. Does a function like cin(c++) need a system call
2. Is there a way to tell if a function uses a system call?

Answer (score 3):

GDB has a "break on syscall" feature. See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html

So the strategy, if you're new to debugging tools, is to set the catchpoint and step over the line calling the function ("next" in gdb). If it breaks before it reaches the line after the function call, then a system call occurred (or the program crashed, I guess).

When you read input using `cin >> ...` a syscall may or may not be invoked. It depends on whether there is already enough data in the buffer. If there isn't enough data in the buffer, then a syscall has to be made to retrieve data from the underlying file or device.

The C++ language doesn't provide an easy built-in way to determine statically whether a function might perform a system call. In fact, a function `foo` might call some `extern` function `bar` which will be compiled separately (in another translation unit) which invokes a system call; the fact that `foo` might indirectly invoke a system call can't be known until link time.